# Symfony 2.8 - How to retrieve data from an entity-less form type?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form without an entity and it is constructed like in the documentation of Symfony:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(['message' => 'Standard message'])
        ->add('....', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => '....',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ])
        ->add('.....', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
        ])
        ->add('....', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
        ])
        ->add('Submit', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();
```

**However, is there any possibility to use a Form Type class and retrieve data back in the controller?** My controllers are becoming pretty large now because there is a lot of form code in there. When I try to shift the code into a separate form type class, it seems like the form is processed but when I try to call $form->getData() inside my controller it is empty. I use the following code:

```
$form = $this->createForm(MyFormType::class);
$form->handleRequest($request);
if($request->isMethod('POST')){
   print_r($form->getData()); // Empty?
   die();
}
```

My form class is as following:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('....', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
        ])
        ->add('....', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
        ])
        ->add('....', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => '....',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ])
        ->add('Submit', SubmitType::class);
    }
}
```

The alternative is to put the code into a separate service but I think it is cleaner to use a form type.

Comment: Are you actually using .... instead of a field name?

Comment: @Cerad No I use a field name but I left it out

Comment: What you have looks like it should work.  Have you confirmed the form is posting correctly by looking at the actual network data?

Comment: Yes. When I print the entire form object with print_r($form) the values are inside the object.

Comment: I eventually came to the conclusion that the $form object indicated that there was a form validation error. That was the problem so it solved now

Comment: Yep, that's why we need to check `$form->isValid()` before get the form data.

Comment: Even with a validation issue I would have expected getData to return the data.  But glad you got it working.